# How can I use stamps to create a shape in turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I tried to do this

```
def ship_merge(*ship_parts, translate_parts = {'part', (x, y)}):
    merge.pu()
    merge.home()
    merge.begin_poly()

    for part in ship_parts:
        merge.home()
        merge.goto(translate_parts[part])
        merge.shape(part)
        merge.stamp()

    merge.end_poly()
    merged_shape = merge.get_poly()
    name = 'Ship 1'
    win.register_shape(name, merged_shape)
    new_ship = turtle.Turtle()
    new_ship.shape(name)
    return new_ship
```

But the 'new_ship' turtle has no shape. I think that it might be the result of the stamps not registering between 'begin_poly' and 'end_poly'. How do I fix this?

Comment: new_ship.showturtle() doesn't affect it at all

Comment: I'd need to see complete code to know for sure, but I believe your issue is that you believe `stamp()` generates a polygon when it doesn't.  Rather than `shape()` and `stamp()`, you'd need to actually *walk* the polygon with `goto()` statements or somesuch.

Comment: Well, thats just great... thanks though!